# How to display firstrow until lastrow in java?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to display first row until last row to JR report using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12275588/how-to-display-first-row-until-last-row-to-jr-report-using-java)

i want to call the record in table from first row until last row and display it ..

i used this syntax :

```
TableModelEvent tab = new TableModelEvent(view.getTable().getModel());
int first = tab.getFirstRow();
int last = tab.getLastRow();
for(int a = first;a<last;a++){
  JTable tables = new JTable(view.getTable().getModel());
  if(tables.getColumnName(3).equals("Price")){
    BigDecimal price = (((BigDecimal)view.getTable().getModel().getValueAt(a,3)));
```

but it just display the data from last row, so what to do to display data from first row until lastrow ?

Comment: Consider posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) to get valuable help. Without context, your snippet does not make much sense and it is hard to understand what you're trying to do and what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

- create [XxxTableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data)
- put [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) to [JScrollPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)
- no idea, doesn't make me sence your [Listening for Data Changes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#modelchange)
- use [tableModel.set/getValueAt(int row, int column)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html)
- for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) with more details about your idea(s)

Comment: @Deni: There's no need to construct a `TableModelEvent`; you can traverse the `TableModel`, as shown in this related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12246000/230513).