# How to copy paste excel values into jtable

Tags: java, excel, swing, jtable

I have a Empty `jtable` and I have a excel sheet with some data in it, I need to copy paste the excel cell values into `jtable` cells how to achieve this?

Comment: Your question only contains requirements - it is not showing any efforts from your side to solve this problem yourself. Please add your attempts to this questions - as this site is not a free "we do your (home)work" service. Beyond that: please turn to the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help)  to learn how/what to ask here. Thanks

Comment: I have tried with apache poi but I cannot understand it a bit all I need the approach to do it

Answer (score 1):

You can import the data from excel to JTable using `JTableReadTableModelTask` , this references should help your problem

http://www.zfqjava.com/article/How-to-import-excel-into-JTabel.html or [how to import datas from excel to jTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31183684/how-to-import-datas-from-excel-to-jtable)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can copy&paste from excell file into JTable, how to do that:

1. You need to research how the clipborad content from excell file
   is structured - copy some data, paste it in notepad and look what are the column and line delimiters.
2. You need to implement the paste event listener for the JTable and some logic
   that will parse the content of the cliboard and insert this data into
   apoppraite fields of your JTable.

**Have fun!**